# Why Python Gensim LDA model is slower when using multicore comparing when using single-core (post shows comparisions)?

Tags: python, performance, gensim, multicore, lda

I'm using a i5 8600 (6 cores and no multithreading).

I'm comparing some topic modelling with LDA inside Gensim and I have no idea why I have these variatons **shown below**. I need to understand it so I can select and apply on a big data. **Someone have a clue what's happening here?**

**1) If I use gensim.models.ldamulticore.LdaMulticore:**

```
coherence = []
for k in range(5,10):
    print('Round: '+str(k))
    Lda = gensim.models.ldamulticore.LdaMulticore
    ldamodel = Lda(corpus, num_topics=k, \
               id2word = id2word, passes=40,\
               iterations=200, chunksize = 10000, eval_every = None, workers=6)
    
    cm = gensim.models.coherencemodel.CoherenceModel(\
         model=ldamodel, texts=texts,\
         dictionary=id2word, coherence='c_v')   
                                                
    coherence.append((k,cm.get_coherence()))
allDone()

executed in 1m 51.1s, finished 17:01:30 2021-06-20
```

**2) If I use gensim.models.LdaMulticore:**

```
coherence = []
for k in range(5,10):
    print('Round: '+str(k))
    Lda = gensim.models.LdaMulticore
    ldamodel = Lda(corpus, num_topics=k, \
               id2word = id2word, passes=40,\
               iterations=200, chunksize = 10000, eval_every = None, workers=6)
    
    cm = gensim.models.coherencemodel.CoherenceModel(\
         model=ldamodel, texts=texts,\
         dictionary=id2word, coherence='c_v')   
                                                
    coherence.append((k,cm.get_coherence()))
allDone()

executed in 1m 54.8s, finished 17:03:40 2021-06-20
```

**3) If I use gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel:**

```
coherence = []
for k in range(5,10):
    print('Round: '+str(k))
    Lda = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel
    ldamodel = Lda(corpus, num_topics=k, \
               id2word = id2word, passes=40,\
               iterations=200, chunksize = 10000, eval_every = None)
    
    cm = gensim.models.coherencemodel.CoherenceModel(\
         model=ldamodel, texts=texts,\
         dictionary=id2word, coherence='c_v')   
                                                
    coherence.append((k,cm.get_coherence()))
allDone()

executed in 1m 37.1s, finished 17:05:17 2021-06-20
```

**4) If i use gensim.models.LdaModel:**

```
coherence = []
for k in range(5,10):
    print('Round: '+str(k))
    Lda = gensim.models.LdaModel
    ldamodel = Lda(corpus, num_topics=k, \
               id2word = id2word, passes=40,\
               iterations=200, chunksize = 10000, eval_every = None)
    
    cm = gensim.models.coherencemodel.CoherenceModel(\
         model=ldamodel, texts=texts,\
         dictionary=id2word, coherence='c_v')   
                                                
    coherence.append((k,cm.get_coherence()))
allDone()

executed in 1m 37.3s, finished 17:06:54 2021-06-20
```

**QUESTIONS**: Someone understand how Gensim functions works and can find the logic in it?

a) If I use Multicore is slower than single core.

b) And if I use  `.ldamodel.LdaModel` I get also another result than using only `.LdaModel` (and the same relation is applied for Multicore).

Many thanks to the community!

Comment: what is the size of your data set here?

Comment: @rchurch4 `Number of lists in list =  1048`
`Total Number of elements :  65629` I thought it would be bigger but the preprocessing made a huge work here; it takes time to tune it though, so I'm testing it with less topics so I can operate latter with more topics with the faster Gensim function.

Comment: @rchurch4 Actually this Number is only  for one DataFrame. I will generate topic models for 30 more DataFrames. It's part of my post-doctoral research, it's for scientific purpose, not industry. The dataset is filled with webnews I webscraped from public secretaries from São Paulo's City Hall (Brazil) official websites.

Comment: That's not a giant diff in performance, nor lengthy jobs. &, using multiprocessing will involve a bit more fanout/merge-results overhead, & likely a lot more memory - which you'd hope would be outweighed by other training speedups across many cores, but might not in some particular setups. Are you sure there's no virtual-mem swapping in any case? (It'd slow things down immensely.) Might the "single-core" version still be achieving a bunch of parallelism via lbrary calls in key bottlenecks? (Does that session show all cores usually saturated? If so, explicit parallelism may not further help.)

Comment: yeah so you're not going to notice the boost in performance on such a small data set. the overhead of managing threads and such will make it slower on such small data sets.

Answer (score 1):

As gojomo and rchurch4 aptly pointed out above, there are multiple factors that can contribute to this situation:

1. Memory pressure / swapping.
2. Overhead for managing parallelism (e.g. splitting the job among parallel threads and combining the results).

Please note though that `gensim` is used for a significantly larger jobs in terms of the corpus size (e.g. [Wikipedia example](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/wiki.html) deals with millions of sentences / words) and with such a size the overhead is well worth the gains from parallelism.

In your case, the corpus may be too small to notice any improvement, and in comparison, small enough to see the impact of the overhead of splitting/merging of the calculations.

Comment: I see. Yes, maybe it's because of the size of the corpus and memory (32GB). Actually is much bigger than this, as I said. It's all institutional news from all secretaries from São Paulo City Hall from 1998 to 2021. I've just used a sample (with few topics) to compare the best way to optimize. Also, the preprocess got it smaller. When I run the model or check coherence may not take too much time, but when I tune, it can take too much time even for a small corpus. I've ran on a full dataset from one secretary and it didn't change much between multicore and single-core. I opted for single core.